# How to add target = "_blank" in case

Tags: javascript

I am using Vanilla 2 as forum with buttonbar plugin to create pre tags in the message area.

When clicking on the **url** button, he generates `<a href=""></a>` in the message box, but I would prefer `<a href="" target="_blank></a>` to generate.

Here is is the .js with the case for the url attribute:

```
case 'url':
           var urlOpts = {};
           var thisOpts = $.extend(htmlOpts, {
              center: 'href'
           });

           var hasSelection = $(TextArea).hasSelection();
           var NewURL = '';
           if (hasSelection !== false) {
              NewURL = hasSelection;
              delete thisOpts.center;
           } else
              NewURL = prompt("Enter your URL:",'http://');

           urlOpts.href = NewURL;

           $(TextArea).insertRoundTag('a',thisOpts,urlOpts);
           break;
```

Can someone tell me how to add the `target="_blank"` in it?

Comment: If you just want to open link in new tab, why not use `window.open()`?

Comment: I don't know exactly the technologies u are using but have u tried with `urlOpts.target = '_blank';` after `urlOpts.href = NewURL;`?

Comment: oke. but can you tell me what i have to change in the code above for that?

Comment: how much more explicit do you need? WHat @ilpaijin provided is self exlanatory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be solved so maybe here could be useful for anyone:

> I don't know exactly the technologies u are using but have u tried with

`urlOpts.target = '_blank';`

before

`$(TextArea).insertRoundTag('a',thisOpts,urlOpts);`